# is it possible to add pagination in ldap get all members query?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldapjs

I am getting all memebers from AD group with the query

```
(&(objectClass=user)
    (memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

But it is just giving first 1000 users in that group because of default pagination.How to get next set of 1000 users results? is it possible to
add pagination in same query?

I am using ldapjs with node.js as a client.Please give some example query with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for LDAPJS talks about this: http://ldapjs.org/client.html#paging

Basically, use the the `paged` property when searching. You may have to set the `sizeLimit` to 1000 (or less) too.

Comment: ok.But I did not find how to query next set of 1000 results in ldapjs.Can you please give some example query?

Comment: You don't need to specifically query the next page. You just set those values and it will do it for you.

Comment: I add the page:true in my code but getting error like
Error: redundant pagedResultControl. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you are using to make the search?